# Resharpers smart code completion CodeRush equivalent

Tags: coderush

I am currently switching from Resharper to CodeRush.

One thing I used a lot in Resharper is the "smart code completion" (Ctrl+Alt+Space) so that in e.g. switch case I could hit the shortcut and Resharper would automatically provide a list of the type that I was switching (typically enums).

Does Coderush have a similar feature?

Comment: I'd love to know if there were any technical reasons you switched away from ReSharper. Please feel free to contact me (hadi at jetbrains). Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by technical reasons. I liked resharper a lot, and especially its intellisense and convert-to-linq feature. My beef with it was mainly speed/performance, I found myself waiting a lot for the intellisense, and also I liked CR's integrated colorpicker.

Answer (score 0):

- Copy the enum variable you wish to switch on, to the clipboard.
- Type **sw[space]**

CodeRush will build you a switch statement with cases for each enum value.

Comment: That's a pretty cool feature. My question is really about a more general use of the intellisense-related code completion.